# How do I remove non-English words in R for most frequent words?

Tags: r

I need help to remove non_English words. 
I used the following codes but when I get to view the head and tail of the text, the tail has non-English words. That means the non-English words were not removed.

When I used this code,

```
for (i in seq(hotel2)) {
    hotel2[[i]] <- gsub('[^a-zA-Z|[:blank:]]', "", hotel2[[i]])
}
```

and run this code for frequent word
 hotel2<-as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(hotel2))

I got an error when I get to view the most frequent words using tdm

> Error in UseMethod("meta", x) :    no applicable method for 'meta'
>   applied to an object of class "character"

When I used this code:

```
removenonenglish <- gsub("[^\x20-\x7E]", "", hotel2)

hotel2 <- tm_map(hotel2, content_transformer(removenonenglish))
```

I got the error below it.

> Error in FUN(content(x), ...) : could not find function "FUN"

Comment: It would probably help if you included a portion of your data, as a data frame, to make your question reproducible.